# I need a for loop that that gives me the dates between 2 dates

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I need a `for` loop that gives me the day and month value between the current date and 7 day's ago for my sqlite3 query. E.G.
`for day in range(7DaysAgo, Today):`

or if there is a better way to get the data from the past 7 days from a database, it would be much appreciated.

this is what i have for 31 days but i need it to be 31 days from the current date and not 31 days  of each month, if that makes sense. I am plotting the data on a matplotlib graph.

```
def animate(i=1):
        var.set((time.strftime("%H:%M")))
        Fig_plot.clear()
        xList_30Day = []
        yList_30Day = []
        
        for DAY in range(31):
            Total_Day = 0
            c.execute('SELECT Day, Month, Bank FROM CRJ WHERE Month=? AND Day=?',(time.strftime("%m"),DAY))
            for row in c.fetchall():
##                print(row)
                Total_Day += row[2]
            xList_30Day.append(DAY)
            yList_30Day.append(Total_Day)
        Fig_plot.plot(xList_30Day,yList_30Day)
```

database column's

CREATE TABLE "CRJ" (
"ID"    REAL,
"Day"   INTEGER,
"Month" INTEGER,
"Year"  INTEGER,
"Time"  INTEGER,
"Description"   TEXT,
"Amount"    RAEL,
"Bank"  RAEL,
"Item"  TEXT,
"QTY"   TEXT,
"Payment_Type"  TEXT,
"Cashier"   TEXT
);

Comment: Do you have a column with the date (and time), separate columns with year, month, day (and time), or what? take a look at the sqlite3 date functions (https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html); you can write something like "where date between date(current_date, '-7 days') and current_date" to get the date interval you need.

Comment: CREATE TABLE "CRJ" (
 "ID" REAL,
 "Day" INTEGER,
 "Month" INTEGER,
 "Year" INTEGER,
 "Time" INTEGER,
 "Description" TEXT,
 "Amount" RAEL,
 "Bank" RAEL,
 "Item" TEXT,
 "QTY" TEXT,
 "Payment_Type" TEXT,
 "Cashier" TEXT
);

Comment: Using SQL only, something like "WHERE printf('%04d-%02d-%02d', Year, Month, Day) between date(current_date, '-7 days') and current_date" could work. Otherwise, you have to possibly split the interval when it falls between two months or two different years; either with a "or" clause in SQL or with two different queries. You may use datetime module in python to calculate the lower limit, then verify if it is in the same month as the upper one, and so on. I don't see any other shortcuts.

Comment: A 31 days interval can actually touch 3 months, from January to March; if it is an option, register the date as date, instead of 3 separate values, would be simpler.

Comment: How would i register it a a date?

Comment: CREATE TABLE "CRJ" ( "ID" REAL,
"Time" DATETIME,
"Description" TEXT,
"Amount" RAEL,
"Bank" RAEL,
"Item" TEXT,
"QTY" TEXT,
"Payment_Type" TEXT,
"Cashier" TEXT ); where DATETIME is a ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS"). I didn't mean anything smarter than that, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, if you really really want a loop in python that gives a date between to dates, you may well get it:

```
from datetime import date as dt, timedelta
today = dt.today()
date = today - timedelta(days=31)
step = timedelta(days=1)

for i in range(31):
    date += step
    ...
    c.execute('SELECT Year, Day, Month, Bank FROM CRJ WHERE Year=?, Month=? AND Day=?',(date.year, date.month, date.day))
    ...
```

It's just that, to me, it doesn't seem a good idea to execute 31 queries if it's possible to get the same with one.